# Hadoop start-dfs script debugging

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop

I'm trying to understand how the `start-dfs.sh` works and noticed this piece of line.

```
NAMENODES=$($HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs getconf -namenodes)
```

Can someone explain what the `getconf` function does here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation says this for `getconf`

> Gets configuration information from the configuration directory

And this for the `namenodes` flag

> gets list of namenodes in the cluster.

Source: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#getconf